# Application Insights + UWP App: What is the expected delay for telemetry data to become available?

Tags: uwp, azure-application-insights

I'm tinkering with Application Insights using a blank UWP app to send telemetry. It seems like all events (PageView, Exception, CustomEvent, etc) take quite long to appear in the Azure Portal (or Visual Studio). I am refreshing the portal page manually.

An example is this CustomEvent that took 14 minutes to become available in Azure:

```
TelemetryClient _tc;
_tc.TrackEvent("A message");
```

...and this is typical for everything I've tried so far.

In the introductory walk-through article, it indicated that data should appear in the portal after a few seconds.

Is it normal for it to take so long? If not, any ideas for resolving the long delays?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Really depends, but *generally* should be on the order of seconds to minutes.

Some of the SDK's / etc batch up events and don't send them immediately, so the event might sit on your computer until some magic amount of events or time has elapsed.  so that could be a delay.

each event type has different processing applied, and your very first events might take time to show up as things on the back end see your events for the first time.  new custom properties or metrics also take time to show up the first time, so even if you see the custom event in the portal, if you look at the details, some of the custom properties might not be there until later.

there's also network/service/azure/etc issues that could occur at any layer of the process.  you can always check http://aka.ms/aistatus to see what, if any latencies are occurring.  From that blog i see an incident that started on 1/13, and went through the time you posted this:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/applicationinsights-status/archive/2016/01/13/experiencing-data-latency-for-many-data-types-01-13-investigating.aspx

> Incident Timeline: 82 Hours - 1/13, 12:30 UTC  through 1/16, 22:30 UTC

Comment: Wouldn't ya know it--the day I decide to give AI a test drive, it's in the middle of some latency issue. Thanks for the help!

Comment: And they are apparently now collecting telemetry data on their telemetry data to investigate more for feasible mitigation ;-)

Comment: we always collect telemetry on our telemetry to investigate our investigations :)